# Display featured products on my native application using WooComerce API?

Tags: c#, api, rest, xamarin.forms, woocommerce

I'm successful in displaying all products on my application but now I need featured products as well.

```
 private static string GetAllProductsApiUrl = string.Format("{0}/wc-api/v3/products?&consumer_key={1}&consumer_secret={2}", website_url, consumer_key, consumer_secret);
    public async Task<Products> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GetAllProductsApiUrl);
        HttpContent content = response.Content;
        var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(json);
        return products;
    }
```

Comment: This question is only related to the API - "Is it possible to query for featured products?" The UI framework does not matter at all as you already know how to display a product.

Comment: BTW Any question here is as urgent as yours and will be treated as any other question - well, some may treat such "urgent" questions with a very low priority

Comment: Thank you Sir for your reply. Actually i m new on this i will follow your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API for list all products has a parameter `featured` to filter only featured products.

Here is the official documentation: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#list-all-products

Comment: Thanks it will help.

Comment: Glad it helped you Abdul.

Comment: I'm adding parameter on my cURL like  [link text](https://www.example.com//wc-api/v3/products?featured=true&consumer_key&consumer_secret) but still not getting featured products

Comment: What response you're getting?

Comment: i m getting products even featured = false too